# Notepad++. Remove all spaces into braces []

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

How can I remove all spaces into braces with Notepad++ and RegEx?

For example:

I have string [Word1 Word2 Word3]
I need: [Word1Word2Word3]

Thanks

Comment: All spaces or all white spaces?

Answer (score 3):

[`\s++(?=[^[]*])`](https://regex101.com/r/bardXk/1)

```
\s++
matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
++ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, without giving back (possessive)
Positive Lookahead (?=[^[]*])
Assert that the Regex below matches
Match a single character not present in the list below [^[]*
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
[ matches the character [ literally (case sensitive)
] matches the character ] literally (case sensitive)
```

[`(?:\[|\G(?!^))[^]\s]*\K\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/bardXk/2)

```
Non-capturing group (?:\[|\G(?!^))
1st Alternative \[
\[ matches the character [ literally (case sensitive)
2nd Alternative \G(?!^)
\G asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match
Negative Lookahead (?!^)
Assert that the Regex below does not match
^ asserts position at start of the string
Match a single character not present in the list below [^]\s]*
* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
] matches the character ] literally (case sensitive)
\s matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
\K resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
\s+
matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```